# How to add environment variables to command line in Django runserver

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I would appreciate it if you could help me.

I want to add some environment variables to command line as following:

python manage.py runserver **myvar=myvar_value**

I use the **myvar** in views.py request function, In fact the servers do different works I want to make a flag with **myvar** to determine if the **myvar** is equal 1, runs some functions in views file and if **myvar** is 0, runs some other function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nicest and most Django way is to use the `settings.py` file for this.

```py
# settings.py
import os

MY_VAR = os.environ.get("MYVAR", default="default")
```

```py
# views.py
from django.conf import settings

def my_view(request):
    my_var = settings.MY_VAR
    # do something with it
```

You can then start the server this way:

```sh
$ MYVAR=foobar python manage.py runserver
```

This is a standard POSIX way to add env vars to called programs. If you then deploy it via Docker you could use a `.env` file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got this error when running views.py.
Exception has occurred: ImproperlyConfigured
Requested setting node_type, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: You can’t run views.py directly. Django must always be launched via the manage.py script or through a WSGI server such asi Gunicorn.

Comment: just for debugging I ran the views, because I have some codes out of request functions. Nevertheless I enter this at command line also I got this error:
node_type=s1 python manage.py runserver
node_type=s1 : The term 'node_type=s1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: You are on Windows? In that case in that case you need to run `set MYVAR=foobar` and then `python manage.py runserver` as two separate commands. My bad, I just assumed everyone uses Linux.

Comment: Excusme me for taking the time, but as the same when running according to your instruction I have the same error:
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'node_type'

Comment: Could you give me a pastebin of your current `settings.py` file?

Comment: I have just tested it and bizzarely enough Django will require you to conform to `SCREAM_CASE_VAR_NAME` since it is a Python global. If you change your variable to `NODE_TYPE` it will work. I did have that in my original answer, except neither of us knew it really was there all the time. Funny...

Comment: It is actually documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/#creating-your-own-settings). I never noticed.

Comment: Now, it works, Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: Glad to help! Could you accept my answer please? Have a nice day!

Comment: as I work on windows powershell I should enter the enviroment variable as follow:
$env:NODE_TYPE = "s1"